# SKScene presented from another SKScene not able to load from SKS file

Tags: swift, xcode

I have quite a specific problem. I used to be presenting my Game Scene from a view controller with the default code. However I Added another SKScene and am now presenting my game scene from that using this code:

```
//In an SKScene (not Game scene)
let scene = GameScene()
let skView = self.view!
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
let push = SKTransition.push(with: SKTransitionDirection.right, duration: 0.4)
skView.presentScene(scene, transition: push)
```

My problem is that my game scene seems to no longer recognize my SKS file as when I run the line of code:

```
//in gamescene
sprite = self.childNode(withName: "sprite") as! SKLabelNode
```

It doesn't find anything when unwrapping. 
When I present my SKScene from GameViewController using the code:

```
if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

        // Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
        if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! GameScene? {

            // Copy gameplay related content over to the scene
            sceneNode.entities = scene.entities
            sceneNode.graphs = scene.graphs

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            sceneNode.scaleMode = .aspectFit

            // Present the scene
            if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                view.presentScene(sceneNode)

                view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: More context is necessary to understand what is happening. It seems like you're writing this code within a `UIViewController` (is this correct?) If so. when you write `self.childNode()...` doesn't self refer to a `UIViewController`? Shouldn't it be `scene.childNode()`? And how do you add the child node in the first place?

Comment: @Acoop I updated my question. Thanks for the commentary, if you need anymore information please ask.

Comment: Thanks. How do you instantiate the sprite to begin with? And why do you create a second `SKView` within the first one, and then replace the `view`?

Comment: @Acoop I would be totally open to a new method of presenting my SKScene(that is sort of what I am looking for), also I am quite sure that the object is not the problem as if I present it from my view controller it works just fine.

Comment: Your scene transition seems fine. (I checked the docs.) However, I still think your issue is in the use of `self.childNode()`. I assume that this line is in the second scene? Is this right? And where was the sprite originally added? To the first scene?

Comment: If GameScene is the second scene then it was created in the second scene's SKS file, and the line is in the second scene.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. I would check your spelling again. This may be the problem. You can also check all the nodes and their names with `for child in self.children{ print child.name }` to see what nodes are actually in the scene. Share anything you find out.

Comment: @Acoop printing the children's names only returned nil three times even though it has 5 children in the SKS file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140021/discussion-between-acoop-and-joshlor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason that it crashes when you present from within the `SKScene`, and not from the `UIViewController` is because of 2 reasons.

1. You are creating 2 different classes, that would probably have different code. When you present from the `SKScene`, you create an object of type `GameScene` but when you present from the `UIViewController` you create an object of type `GKScene`.
2. When you create the object of type `GameScene`, you use an initializer that does not take into account the attached SKS File. But when you create the object of type `GKScene` you do.

Therefore, I would edit the first block of code to be:

```
//In an SKScene (not Game scene)
if let sceneContainer = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
    let skView = self.view!
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    //Something comparable to the following line. I don't have a project set up, but let the compiler run you through the exact syntax.
    let scene = sceneContainer.rootNode as! GameScene?
    scene?.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    let push = SKTransition.push(with: SKTransitionDirection.right, duration: 0.4)
    skView.presentScene(scene!, transition: push)
}
```

The doc for getting the `SKScene` from a `GKScene` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gameplaykit/gkscene/1640947-rootnode).